# Declare dynamic array in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

Is there an easy way to declare a dynamic array in Oracle PL/SQL?

I need to use an array that can contain 100,000 numbers and other times I need to store only 3 numbers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are three types of collection in PL/SQL. Only the `varrays` have a fixed maximum number of elements. If you use a [nested table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDHIGFH) or an [associative array](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDEIDIC) instead, you can add as many element as you want.

For further reading: [PL/SQL Collections and Records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHIEBJC)