# Could anyone help me to resolve below mentioned error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing this oracle PSQL error ORA-06533

```
Declare
  type empidvarray is varray(6) of employees.id%type;
  empid_array empidvarray:=empidvarray();
  c_empid employees.id%type;
  i integer(2);
  counter number(2);
begin
  select count(*) into counter from employees;
  select id into c_empid from employees where id =1;
  empid_array.extend;
  empid_array(10):=c_empid; -- array is trying to assigning the value of uninitialized position 10.
end;
```

> ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit 
>   ORA-06512: at line 11

Can someone help to resolve PLSQL question asked on?

https://techytraining.com/forum/topic/plsql-exception/

Comment: did you try to use a search? maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945293/ora-06533-subscript-beyond-count/28945698

Comment: it looks like you're trying to assign a value to an array in its position 10, when its size it's 6. I would recommend searching how .extend works. and also check here on how to ask good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare
type empno_arr is varray(100) of emp.empno%type;
empno_arry empno_arr:=empno_arr();
c_empno emp.empno%type;
counter number(10);
begin
select count(*) into counter from emp;
select empno into c_empno
          from emp 
           where empno =7369;
empno_arry.extend(10);--Need to provide the  length of extend array. Otherwise it will consider as  index 1
empno_arry(10):=c_empno; -- array is trying to assigning the value of uninitialized position 10.
end;
```

Comment: Array index will start from 1,so you need to provide the extend length of the varray, as shown above code