# Setting the size of a varray to the result of a count SQL statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to store the result of a fairly simple `select` statement in a `varray`

```
select id from my_table where column1 is not null;
```

Ideally, I'd declare my `varray` and set its size to be

```
select count(id) from my_table where column1 is not null;
```

something like this pseudo-code:

```
type my_array_type is varray(select count(id) from my_table where column1 is not null) of int;

my_array my_array_type := my_array_type();

my_array.extend(select count(id) from my_table where column is not null);

FOR i IN 1..my_array.count LOOP    
  my_array(i) := <get id from select statement using cursor>;
END LOOP;
```

Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Surely the varray's limit is the whole point of it? If there is no particular limit then use a nested table and not a varray.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson so the only way to initialise a ``varray`` is by hardcoding the length in?

Comment: @ChrisW. You need to understand why and when we generally use Varray. Oracle has defined varray for the places where we are sure of size. Oracle gives associated arrays and nested tables for other scenarios

Comment: As of 12.1, yes. The [PL/SQL Expressions Enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/release-changes.htm#GUID-31C2E9C9-4C2F-4062-A818-8CB2BB8FF337) in 12.2 might let you, though I haven't tried. As a general rule, though, VARRAYs aren't useful in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic size initialization with varray is not possible,you can try Nested table instead of it.

(By reference of [Declare dynamic array in Oracle PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613244/declare-dynamic-array-in-oracle-pl-sql))

Please check sample code mentioned below.

```
DECLARE
    type my_array_type is TABLE  of MY_TABLE.COLUMN1%TYPE;

    l_employees my_array_type;
BEGIN
-- All rows at once...
  SELECT COLUMN1      
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_employees
    FROM MY_TABLE
   ORDER BY COLUMN1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_employees.COUNT);

  FOR indx IN 1 .. l_employees.COUNT
  LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_employees(indx));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Hope this will help you!